# Make an iOS "forward" button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

This is kind of a tough thing to search for because of how general the words are.  I would like to make a "forward" button for my app, much like the standard iOS navigation "back" button, but obviously pointing the other direction.

So my question is simple: Is there a standard way of adopting the "back" button style, and simply flipping it to make it point to the right?  Or do I have to make a custom button background?

Here is a quick 'shopped screenshot of what I would like.

[image: Back and continue buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button has a set functionality, it pops the current view controller in the navigation controller and returns to the previous one. A forward button does not have a clear semantic as you can push any view controller onto your navigation controller, which is why UIKit doesn't offer it. You'll probably have to emulate it (copying and flipping the graphics), then systematically push a given view controller when the user presses it.

Comment: Yeah, I already have a "continue" button on all of my screens, there is a very set progression of views for my app, so this kind of behavior does make sense.  Its just the graphic I need, so it seems I need to make my own graphic.  Alright, at least I can make a simple stretchable image to cover all of the "forward" buttons I could need